# Why won't this javascript work?

Tags: php, javascript

It's been really frustrating me i have this code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
scriptAr = new Array(); // initializing the javascript array

<?php

foreach ($docsannlist as $subdocs) 
{
    $lines = $subdocs; // read file values as array in php
    $count = count($subdocs); //this gives the count of array
    //In the below lines we get the values of the php array one by one and update it in the script array.
    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
        print "scriptAr.push(\"$line\");\n"; // This line updates the script array with new entry
    }
}

?>

document.write(scriptAr);
</script>
```

and for some reason its just not working. Please help!

Comment: In what way does it fail to work? What's the HTML output? Anything in the error console?

Comment: Jeeze, now I feel bad for breaking ranks. I didn't notice the non-existent accepts - honest! Feel like I've betrayed you guys (as well as wasting my time) now...

Comment: @Tom Don't worry, I would've answered if I thought I knew what the problem was :)

Comment: The "title" of this question is pathetic. Can someone with the required rep please edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably not in your javascript code.

My guess is that you have **string escaping** problems. Try to use `addslashes` php function on the `$line` variable before printing.

```
// as simple as that
$line = addslashes($line);
```

Because if a line has a quote your PHP will work fine but your javascript will look like this:

```
scriptAr.push("some text here "a quotation" and some other text");
```

Which is **invalid syntax**.

If you use `addslashes`, the line will become:

```
scriptAr.push("some text here \"a quotation\" and some other text");​​
```

Which will run just fine.

Comment: `addslashes` is nearly but not quite good enough to escape a string for JavaScript. The Unicode characters U+2028 and U+2029 will act as newlines if not escaped (to eg. `\u2028`), and the sequence `</script>`, if included in a string, will terminate a script block early if you're inside one. (Actually just `</` is theoretically enough.)

Comment: Thinking about newline yes it can be improved, but there's nothing better than JSON. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't "write()" an array. An array is just a collection of objects (in your case, strings).

You'll need to loop through it and print each element in turn:

```
for(var i in scriptAr) { 
    document.write(i + " => " + scriptAr[i] + "<br>\n"); 
}
```

All this does is iterate over each element and print it. Those square brackets are for the index (the variable "i" in this case) which is used to address individual elements.

Comment: except **you can**... using an object/array in this way it invokes the toString() method which in this case outputs the elements separated by comma...

Comment: True, but I've always found the output to be pretty ugly.

Comment: but your personal taste doesn't solve any of the OP's problem.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
print "scriptAr.push(\"$line\");\n";
```

That's going to cause problems if there are any characters in `$line` that confuse a JavaScript string literal, such as `"`, `\`, `</script>` or a newline.

```
document.write(scriptAr);
```

That's dodgy, as you can't write an array directly. It'll get `toString`​ified, which will add a load of commas in between the lines.

There's already a good function to turn PHP variables (including arrays) into JavaScript literals, `json_encode`:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    var docs= <?php echo json_encode($docsannlist, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;

    // Flatten docs list-of-list-of-lines into list-of-lines
    //
    var lines= [];
    for (var i= 0; i<docs.length; i++)
        lines= lines.concat(docs[i]);

    document.write(lines.join(''));
</script>
```

Although I'm not wholly sure what the advantage of passing a bunch of content through `document.write()` is, rather than just outputting it as-is. `document.write()` is generally to be avoided.